# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04: Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card, Globally?

Tags: gnome, graphics, amd-graphics

Having heard the news about Ubuntu's coming move back to Gnome Desktop, I've decided to embrace this change earlier and upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to **Ubuntu Gnome 17.04**, and I'm quite happy about it.

I've already begun enjoying some advantages, like the straightforward option of **using the Dedicated AMD Graphics Card** instead of the Integrated Intel Graphics when launching applications as seen in the screenshot. This is very helpful especially considering that AMD has stopped supporting Ubuntu after version **15.04** for my hybrid graphics card...[image]

However, I wonder (given the fact that **vga-switcheroo** is practically useless for me) if there's any way of **enabling this option globally** in some way so that **all** applications (e.g. when a file is clicked to open in the default application) run using the Dedicated Graphics Card. What I have in mind is that I'd rather have all apps use the Dedicated Graphics Card when the computer is not running on battery power...

**NOTE:** It is also possible to launch **individual apps** using the dedicated GPU by running them with the environment variable `DRI_PRIME=1` (e.g. `DRI_PRIME=1 inkscape`) from terminal. And this can be achieved by manually editing desktop configuration files, and inserting `env DRI_PRIME=1` to the `Exec=` line (e.g. `Exec=env DRI_PRIME=1 inkscape %F`).

Comment: Don't know exactly why, but the onboard intel opens faster then the AMD Radeon... About 4 secs better to open a java app

Answer (score 3):

If I'm right what you want to ask is, how run a specific app on dGPU always, instead of right clicking on it and selecting `Run dedicated GPU`.

It mostly depends on the `Desktop Environment`.

Here is screenshot from my `KDE` setup:

[image]

Here I have checked it to run on a dedicated GPU and now it always runs on the dGPU, I'm not sure if gnome does it bt if you explore into the launcher editor you might find a option to set it permanently.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is yet another reason to consider switching to KDE ;-)
Unfortunately Gnome desktop configuration files don't offer anything like this. I think this  can only be implemented in Gnome by manually inserting `env DRI_PRIME=1` to the `Exec=` line. However, I think I would ideally prefer using discrete GPU globally (instead of configuring individual apps) when the computer is not running on battery power.

Comment: Do you know how to do it with GNOME?

Answer (score 2):

need to add this two lines to .desktop file *(ussualy there is in **~/.local/share/application** or **/usr/share/applications**)*

```
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=true
```

then reboot

Comment: Thanks man! "Reboot" is the most important part. Upvoted!